# Trying to move Microsoft Authenticator to new iPhone

Tags: iphone

I work for a company, let's call it ABC that forces me to use the infamous Microsoft Authenticator. I have it working on an iPhone 11. This company gave me an email, let's say duck@abccorp.com.

MS Authenticator is working fine with this email and device.

As a particular customer, I have purchased MS Office 365 on my own and for that reason I have it registered under, let's say, myself@gmail.com.

I have purchased a new iPhone 14 and I am trying to transfer MS Authenticator from iPhone 11 to 14.

No way to make it work.

After fiddling with MS Authenticator on iPhone 11, I have managed to turn iCloud backup on the iPhone 11, but just using my particular email myself@gmail.com.

What are the steps to move MSA from one iPhone to another one? I have tried every tutorial I have found.

I am using my personal account as a backup hoping to see a button called RESTORE on the second iPhone but this button appeared once and never more.

Any idea?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked onto this but I *think* you just need to sign into MS Authenticator with the same email you used on the previous device under iCloud backup.

Comment: It's probably easier to just install Authenticator on the new phone and then go through your company's enrollment process again.